# Get the TaskGroup Version used in a VSTS Release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In VSTS I have a release pipeline that executes a TaskGroup and this TaskGroup has different versions.

What I'm trying to do is every time the pipeline runs, get this value in my code to have a detailed log of what Version was used in each deployment. Another option could be sending it to a blob and later reading from there, but the first step is accessing the Version used in the pipeline.

This is the Version I'm refering to:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the task group version which used in the release pipeline by REST API. Details as below:

1. **Add a task [get release definition REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/definitions/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1)**

   Such as you can add a PowerShell task to request the REST API:

   ```
   GET https://{accountName}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=4.1-preview.3
   ```
2. **Filter the task group from the response of the REST API and get the task group’s version**

   From the response of REST API, you can search the task group from `workflowTasks` object, and get the task group’s version correspondingly.

   As below example, the Task group: copy and publish version used in the release pipeline is `2.*`.

   ```
   {
       "taskId": "0bddeb71-4b7f-46b9-8264-8f2b4a1010b7",
       "version": "2.*",
       "name": "Task group: copy and publish ",
       "refName": "",
       "enabled": true,
       "alwaysRun": true,
       "continueOnError": true,
       "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
       "definitionType": "metaTask",
       "overrideInputs": {},
       "condition": "succeededOrFailed()",
       "inputs": {}
   }
   ```

Besides, you can also add an [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services) to suggest to show task group's verision used in build/release pipeline.